# Run javascript when loading a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I have an app that shows the active menu with javascript, it is an app made with Cordova.
The problem is that when I press the button to go back, it does not show me the active menu, the previous one is still here.
Is there a possibility to solve this? What I do is with javascript hide the non-active image and show the active image when pressed.
I have attached the code here:

```
<body>

<script>
    var webAppWindow;
</script>
<iframe id="elframe" src="https://uoapp.es/cuenta/" name="iframe" style="position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 94%; "
    onLoad="cambioiframe();"></iframe>


<div class="navbar">
    <img src="img/logo-uo.png"
        style="position: fixed;left: 50%; bottom: 0px; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 120px;" alt="logo"></a>

    <a href="https://uoapp.es/blog" target="iframe"><img src="img/icons8-news-64-active.png"
            style="position: fixed; left: 0%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px; display: none;" id="blog-activo"
            alt="blog"></a>
    <a href="https://uoapp.es/blog" target="iframe" onclick="mostraricono1();"><img src="img/icons8-news-64.png"
            style="position: fixed;left: 0%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px;" id="blog-no-activo" alt="blog"></a>

    <div class="contacto">
        <a href="https://uoapp.es/contacto" target="iframe"><img src="img/icons8-group-message-64-active.png"
                style="position: fixed;left: 15%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px; display: none;" id="contacto-activo"
                alt="contacto"></a>
        <a href="https://uoapp.es/contacto" target="iframe" onclick="mostraricono2();"><img
                src="img/icons8-group-message-64.png" style="position: fixed;left: 15%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px;"
                id="contacto-no-activo" alt="contacto"></a>

        <a href="https://uoapp.es/directorio/" target="iframe"><img src="img/icons8-page-64-active.png"
                id="directorio-activo" alt="directorio"
                style="position: fixed;left: 72%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px; display: none;"></a>
        <a href="https://uoapp.es/directorio/" target="iframe" onclick="mostraricono3();"><img
                src="img/icons8-page-64.png" id="directorio-no-activo" alt="directorio"
                style="position: fixed;left: 72%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px;"></a>

        <a href="https://uoapp.es/cuenta/" target="iframe"><img src="img/icons8-user-male-64-active.png"
                id="cuenta-activo" alt="cuenta"
                style="position: fixed;left: 86%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px; display: none;"></a>
        <a href="https://uoapp.es/cuenta/" target="iframe" onclick="mostraricono4();"><img
                src="img/icons8-user-male-64.png" id="cuenta-no-activo" alt="cuenta"
                style="position: fixed;left: 86%; bottom: 0px; width: 50px;"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    <p id="OneSignalUserId"></p>
    <p style="word-break: break-all;" id="OneSignalPushToken"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

Javascript code is:

```
function mostraricono1() {
  const blog_noactivo = document.getElementById('blog-no-activo');
  blog_noactivo.style.display = "none";
  const blog_activo = document.getElementById('blog-activo')
  blog_activo.style.display = "block";

  const contacto_noactivo = document.getElementById('contacto-no-activo');
  contacto_noactivo.style.display = "block";
  const contacto_activo = document.getElementById('contacto-activo')
  contacto_activo.style.display = "none";

  const directorio_noactivo = document.getElementById('directorio-no-activo');
  directorio_noactivo.style.display = "block";
  const directorio_activo = document.getElementById('directorio-activo')
  directorio_activo.style.display = "none";

  const cuenta_noactivo = document.getElementById('cuenta-no-activo');
  cuenta_noactivo.style.display = "block";
  const cuenta_activo = document.getElementById('cuenta-activo')
  cuenta_activo.style.display = "none";


}
```

That is the function show icons 1 then there are the other 3 functions that are identical for each image

I hope someone can help me.
 If someone can, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions is to give them serial id or serial class name , put for the first one

id = 'id1' and the second element give it an id = 'id2' and so on

then we gonna handle it in the java script using a counter like

```
var i = 1 ;
```

so if you want an element of id1 ,it gonna be ('id'+i) and after clicking the next button ,the counter increase (i++) and when clicking the previous button the counter decrease (i--)

below is an example of what i mean

```js
   
   // get all the elemnts of the main div 
   var selectedDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.contacto div')
   // the counter 
   var i = 1;

    function btnRing(clicked_id) {
    
    // this for hide all the elements inside the main div 
    //when clicking any button the all elements is gonna hide
    selectedDiv.forEach(div => {
            div.style.display = "none"
        })

    // this for next button
        if (clicked_id === 'btn1') {
    // this line to make the previous button active when clicking the next button
         document.getElementById('btn2').style.pointerEvents = 'all'
     //this to show the next element
            document.getElementById('div' + (i + 1)).style.display = 'block'
            
     // increase the counter when clicking next       
            i++
    // this for deactivating the next button when is there is no more elements        
            if (i >= 4) {
                document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.pointerEvents = 'none'
            }

    //this is the previous button
        } else if (clicked_id === 'btn2') {
   // this for activating the next button after i deactivate it above
            document.getElementById('btn1').style.pointerEvents = 'all'
      //decrease the counter      
            i--
            
       // showing the previous elemnt     
            document.getElementById('div' + i).style.display = 'block'
     
     //this for deactivating the previous button after is no more elements

            if (i <= 1) {
                document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.pointerEvents = 'none'
            }

        }





    }
```

```css
        #div1,
        #div2,
        #div3,
        #div4 {
            height: 10rem;
            width: 10rem;
            background-color: brown;
            color: aliceblue;
            display: none;
        }
        
        #div1 {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="contacto">
        <div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
        <div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
        <div id="div3">DIV 3</div>
        <div id="div4">DIV 4</div>


    </div>
    <button id='btn1' onclick="btnRing(this.id)">next</button>
    <button id='btn2' onclick="btnRing(this.id)">previous</button>
```